# Bad saving in Unity 3D with JSON

Tags: json, unity-game-engine, save

My source code of voxel terrain can't save the data. I have a 3D char array called terrain and when I save, then it's result is empty json. The result is:

```
{}
```

The source code is:

```
public void TerrainSave() {
    LoadingSavingClass myObject = new LoadingSavingClass();
    myObject.terrain = terrain;
    string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(myObject);
    File.WriteAllText(Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/terrain/save.ter", json);
    if(json == "{}")
    {
        Debug.Log("Saved clear data");
    }
}
```

The class is:

```
[Serializable]
public class LoadingSavingClass
{
    public char[,,] terrain = new char[128, 32, 128];
}
```

The saved 3D char char array isn't empty, I put some data into it before saving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned here in [JSON Serialization Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JSONSerialization.html) JsonUtility.ToJson will only serialize the same types as you can serialize in Unity's inspector. char[,,,] won't serialize in Unity's inspector so it won't serialize with JsonUtility.ToJson